# Sudoku Conjecture about rows and columns

Tags: puzzle

In the game of Sudoku, if all the columns and rows are properly filled, will that assure all the boxes will be properly filled?

Answer (score 12):

Counter example:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|ccc|ccc} \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{2} & \color{red}{3} & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\color{blue}{2} & \color{red}{3} & \color{blue}{4} & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 1 \\
\color{red}{3} & \color{blue}{4} & \color{blue}{5} & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
7 & 8 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
8 & 9 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 \\
9 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\end{array}\right]$$

Every box is not properly filled as the anti-diagonal has identical element.

Comment: Thanks and alas, that means when checking a solution, the boxes also (shucks) have to be checked.